torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError when training model on GPU, but not for larger batch sizes on CPU
I am working on training a MultiModal model in PyTorch. I have a training loop which runs just fine (albeit slowly) on my CPU (I tested up to batch size = 32). However, when I try to run it on a GPU (Tesla P40), it only works up to batch size = 2. With larger batch sizes it throws a torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError. I am working with pre embedded video and audio, and pre tokenized text. Is it possible that the GPU can really not handle batch sizes larger than 2 or could there be something wrong in my code? Do you have any advice on how I might go about troubleshooting? I apologize for this simple question, it is my first time working with a GPU cluster. I am running this code on my university's GPU cluster and have double checked that the GPU I am using is not being used by anyone else.
I tried to examine memory usage on both the CPU and the GPU. By running nvidia-smi, I found that each GPU has a memory limit of 23040 MiB. I used print(f'Allocated: {torch.cuda.memory_allocated() / 1024**2} MB') print(f'Cached: {torch.cuda.memory_reserved() / 1024**2} MB') to track the memory usage of the GPU and found that after all data is loaded with a batch size of 8, only around 500 MB are allocated and around 2000 MB are cached. The error tends to occur when calling BERT to embed the text tokens, but may occur later with smaller batch sizes. I also double checked that all tensors are being properly loaded onto the GPU.

It's normal that you can use much large batch sizes on CPU vs GPU (but much slower).
In general with language models, the memory used per batch is a function of the sequence lengths (and obviously the batch size). If you can set this lower you may not experience as many out-of-memory issues. If for example you're using the huggingface library you can set the maximum sequence length and truncate using:
tokenizer(text, truncation=True, max_length=128)

This may of course cause problems if you have long and informative text, but sometimes out-of-memory can surface in a single pathological batch because it contains as single example that's much longer than normal. Because each batch is (usually) padded to the length of the longest example, the entire batch becomes much larger than usual. This causes training to fail part way through the epoch.

Thanks for the help! I actually found out that the problem was with someone using most resources on the server upon closer examination, but I will keep this in mind for the future.
